# Retrofit + GSON returns NULL for RegExp

Tags: android, regex, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit 2.0 in my app with GSON converter.

In my JSON i have 6 fields, 3 for int and String and 3 of them consists of RegExps (1 int for "id" and 5 String fields in model Class).

String and int fiends were parsed very well, but on fields with RegExp GSON returns NULL.

Here's example of JSON:

```
[
   {
     "id": "22",
     "iso": "TTR",
     "name": "Lolo",
     "check": "^77",
     "full": "^77[0-9]{9}$",
     "default": "+77"
   },
   {
     "id": "23",
     "iso": "RTT",
     "name": "Polo",
     "check": "^7",
     "full": "^7[0-6,8,9][0-9]{9}$",
     "default": "+7"
   }
]
```

and code in fragment:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(URL_API)
         .client(SSLSuppressClient.trustcert())
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .build();
GetPhones getPhonesInfo = retrofit.create(GetPhones.class);
Call<ArrayList<GetPhones> call = getPhonesInfo.getPhones();
call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<GetPhones>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ArrayList<GetPhones>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("LOG", t.getMessage());
                }
    });
```

and model class:

```
public class GetPhones {
    int id;
    String iso;
    String name;
    String lop_check;
    String lop_full;
    String lop_default;
}
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Remove `,` from character class .`^7[0-6,8,9][0-9]{9}$` ==> `^7[0-689][0-9]{9}$`

Comment: @Tushar unfortunately this is not my JSON, so I can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should declare the field `String full` in `GetPhones` or if you want use a different name for it you have to use the annotation  `@SerializedName`. E.g.

```
@SerializedName("default")
String lop_default;
```

in this case Gson will use `full` as key for parsing your json. In general this applies to every field you want to parse. Otherwise you will always get a null/default value

Comment: Accordingly to the response you posted you should be using `Call<List<GetPhone>>`

Comment: yeap! I'm using ArrayList.

Comment: I am clueless then, sorry

Comment: You're right! I found mistake in naming! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It will return null because Retrofit unable to find mapping for phone_ftm_check variable.

You need to add @SerializedName("check") annotation over your variable declaration.

So your POJO class should be looks like below :

```
public class GetPhones {
    int id;
    String iso;
    String name;
    @SerializedName("check")
    String phone_ftm_check;
    @SerializedName("full")
    String phone_ftm_full;
    @SerializedName("default")
    String phone_ftm_default;
}
```

Try this POJO class. It will work.

Comment: You can not use default as variable name. JAVA not allow it.

Comment: Yeap! It's stupid question about naming)) Thank you for the help!